# check UItextfield name

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am accessing textFieldShouldReturn to check if the textfield equals the initalized type, however I am not sure how to do it.

This is what my textFieldShouldReturn method looks like.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:textField.tag+1] becomeFirstResponder];
    // this means there has been a change in the UItextfield
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedItemDictionary);
    if ([textField isEqual:cell.widthTextField]) {

//..
```

And then cell.widthTextField is a subclassed UITableViewCell with several UITextFields in it. Once of which is called widthTextField.

So my question is, how do you know which textField you are actually in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITextFields` do not have "names". You can give your text field a tag and use that.

Also, note that (pointer == pointer) will only return true if you are referencing the same objects, not equivalent values.

Here is how to use the tag: in Interface Builder, give each text field a tag, or if you create your text fields programmatically, set textField.tag = someInt; I usually use macros to make the code more readable:

```
#define kNameTextField 2
#define kAddressTextField 3
```

...

```
if (textField.tag == kNameTextField) ...
```

With lots of fields like that, I prefer enums:

```
typedef enum {
  kNameTextField = 2, 
  kAddressTextField, 
  kPhoneTextField // etc
} Fields;
```

Comment: YES! thanks very much I have .tags set and this helped jogg my mind of the fact. so its all working now. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can check..

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if (textField == [self yourTextField]) {
     //Do your code
  }
}
```

Comment: This code give "expected identifier" error. I think cause of the subclassed cell.